# Matrix with simplified EngineeringForm

Tags: matrix

I have the following numerical matrix:

```
Ds={{0.0002773500981126146, -0.0002773500981126146},{0.0005547001962252292, 
-0.0002773500981126146}}
```

I would like to express it in engineering form.
I have tried:

```
Ds//EngineeringForm
```

The result is a matrix with each entry in Engineering Form. My question is: is it possible to obtain this matrix as the product of 10^-6 and the resulting Ds?

Answer (score 1):

```
Inactivate[ 10^-6 Activate[Ds 10^6], Times]
```

[image]

```
Inactivate[ 10^-6   Activate[Ds 10^6], Times|Power]
```

[image]

```
Inactivate[HoldForm[10^-6]Activate[Ds 10^6], Times]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I write 1/1000000 in the Engineering form?

Comment: @GaeP, use `Times|Power` in place of `Times` in `Inactivate[...]`.

Comment: I would like to have TraditionalForm[10^-6] but it seems doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple possibilities:

```
EngineeringForm[10^-6] EngineeringForm[Ds 10^6]
Defer[10^-6] EngineeringForm[Ds 10^6]
```

[image]